# Addon credentials of password api firefox sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created an addon.I want it to be password protected.I have no  idea how to use addon credentials of password api to store and search credentials.Need help

Comment: i dont understand. what exactly do you want to protect? if you want to protect something with a password how would storing and searching help? give me an example of a password you would like to store, or would like to search and ill post an example of that

Comment: @Noitidart my addon is to block sites the user wants.So user ips the sites in panel.I need to verify the user each time the widget is clicked.Only the authorized user can view,edit and modify the sites to be blocked.For this first user have to register right?then after that the code need to verify the user by searching the stored credentials right?

Comment: what do you mean "ips panel". you don't have to have the user register. you can tell the user to use a master password and promp them to enter the master password everytime they try to access the panel. in fact i recomend this way so you don't have to create a web site to have them sign up. if user is not using a master password then you should let them edit the sites to be blocked without prompting for a password. if this is the way you want to go let me know and i'll help you out.

Comment: @Noitidart yeah master password is what i want.

Comment: ok ill learn it and then post back i havent ever done it myself, but anything is doable

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comment, it seems like you're looking for the [`passwords` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/passwords#search%28options%29).

E.g. store the password:

```
require("sdk/passwords").store({
  realm: "My add-on credentials",
  user: "Restricted preferences",
  url: require("sdk/self").uri,
  password: "some user supplied password",
});
```

E.g. retrieve and compare the password:

```
function login(password, callback) {
  require("sdk/passwords").search({
    realm: "My add-on credentials",
    user: "Restricted preferences",
    url: require("sdk/self").uri,
    onComplete: function onComplete(credentials) {
      if (!credentials.length) {
        callback(false);
      }
      else {
        callback(credentials[0].password == password);
      }
    }
   });
}

login("supersecret", function(ok) {
  console.log("login " + (ok ? "success" : "failure");
});
```

Comment: i get the logic to store and search the password.But where do i get the user to enter the password first?Is it possible for me to get password from the user on clicking the widget?Only after entering the right password panel should be shown.doable?

Answer (score 0):

Ok man I created a code snippet for you [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9300413), read the comments on the page below ill summarize here though:

> login argument is false meaning that if the user had previously entered their master password it will not prompt them now AND if they had not entered it before and it is still valid for the session it will NOT prompt. IF you set it to true then regardless if the user entered it in before or not it will force them to enter it again. IF no master password set always returns true

copy paste this code:

```
var me = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null);
var tokenDB = Cc['@mozilla.org/security/pk11tokendb;1'].getService(Ci.nsIPK11TokenDB);
var master_password = tokenDB.getInternalKeyToken();

var master_password_authenticated;
try {
    master_password_authenticated = Components.isSuccessCode(token.login(false));
} catch (ex) {
    master_password_authenticated = false;
}

me.alert('master passsword pass? = ' + master_password_authenticated);
```

Comment: @Ram it automatically opens is this what you were looking for? If not let me know

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is the code you need to enforce the user to key in the master password.

It uses the recent SDK version, using `jpm`.

e.g. the following is the content of the `index.js` file:

```
const {Cc, Cu, Ci} = require('chrome');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

let tokenDB = Cc['@mozilla.org/security/pk11tokendb;1'].getService(Ci.nsIPK11TokenDB);
let token = tokenDB.getInternalKeyToken();

function isSuccessCode(returnCode) {
    return (returnCode & 0x80000000) === 0;
}

try {
    // In here, we put the flag as true, to show the prompt 
    // regardless there was a successful attempt or not. 
    if (isSuccessCode(token.login(true))) {
       // do something here
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```